# Why we use dependencies keyword in {theme}libraries.yml ? and not just include the file?

Tags: javascript

in the **{theme}.libraries.yml** why we need to declare the jquery js or any other library as a **depedency** :

```yml
  js: 
    assets/lib/bootstrap-4.0.0-dist/js/bootstrap.js: {}
    assets/script.js: {}

 dependencies: 
     - core/jquery
```

an not just include it for example as a simple js, before all other js that depends on it :

```yml
  js:
    assets/jquery.js: {} # load dependency library before the dependent libraries.
    assets/lib/bootstrap-4.0.0-dist/js/bootstrap.js: {}
    assets/script.js: {}
```

in the 2nd scenario the js file ex: jquery will be loaded before the other js files.

so what is the difference?

Comment: If every module adds his own jQuery file, instead of the jQuery core dependency, you would end up with a LOT of unnecessary duplicated JS libs massivly bloating your website.

Comment: because that pulls in that library, not just the jquery file, where it (a library) may have a few files it needs to function right.

Comment: It also ensures if the file path changes for any reason, it doesn't break your library.

Comment: @Kevin thank u I get the point we depend on a library that can consist of a set of files, and not just one file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A library is a set of files (CSS or JavaScript) which could be local or loaded from another site. Declaring a dependency from another library has the vantage of not requiring to know:

- Which files need to be loaded
- Where those files are located
- Which dependencies that library has

Using a library and declaring its dependencies also means that:

- A file is loaded only once
- There is only a copy of a file for all the modules
- A module that depends from a library doesn't need to update the list of files (which are part of that library) when the library changes its files